# Combine all web page source into single index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, web

**Input:** an index.html with many external .js and .css files; no images.

**Desired output:** a new html file ('index_combined.html') that contains ALL the source.

How does one go about doing this in an automated fashion?

(The only definite way I can think of is using PhantomJS to render the page to html, but that's a bit heavyweight and has side effects.)

Comment: There are _many_ different tools and techniques for doing so.  Do you have any build process at all at the moment to narrow the scope of this question somewhat?

Comment: I should be able to initiate it from a Linux command line, that's all. I'd love to hear about a couple tools/techniques!